# Map UNC Path to local folder

Tags: windows-11, hosts, unc

I would like to map a local folder to a UNC Path.

i.e. I have a folder, `c:\temp` that I'd like to access locally via `\\media-server\temp`

I've tried adding an entry to my HOSTS file,

```
127.0.0.1 media-server
```

And shared folder as "temp"

but when I try and access `\\media-server\temp` I am given a prompt to logon. No credentials seem to work.

I am on Windows 11.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To help others, I solved by making the below registry edits

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters Add a new Multi-String value called OptionalNames. Enter one or more aliases, one per line.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters Add a new DWORD value called DisableStrictNameChecking and set to 1.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters Add a new DWORD value called DisableLoopBackCheck and set to 1.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
Add a new Multi-String Value BackConnectionHostNames. Enter one or more aliases, one per line.

You’ll have to cycle the machine for the configuration to take effect.

reference: https://blog.malevy.net/2010/05/creating-netbios-alias-for-local.html